# Workflow is not shown so I cannot run it manually (Github Actions)

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I created the workflow `Test` but there is no `Run workflow` button to run it manually.

[image]

This is my `test.yml` file. Is there anything missing?

```
name: Test

on:
  release:
    types: [created]
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to put `workflow_dispatch:` under `on:`.

```
name: Test

on:
  release:
    types: [created]
  workflow_dispatch: # Put here!!
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!
```

Then, a `Run workflow` button is shown.

[image]

[image]

It's ok to put `workflow_dispatch:` before `release:`. It works as well.

```
name: Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch: # Putting here is also fine!!
  release:
    types: [created]
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!
```

Comment: This is the clearest answer

Comment: I agree with @EatatJoes. This answer shows exactly what to do. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I've put it but still don't have the Run workflow button. What might be the reason?

Comment: @mecdeality the change has to be merged to your default branch before the button apperas.

Answer (score 70):

Some workflows, such as those, based on `workflow_dispatch` event, the workflow **will not even show until the code is on the `main`** (or default branch).

The good news is, once you do merge your feature to `main`, you may keep on working on the feature branch. From then on, you will have the option to choose which branch you want to run the workflow on , like in the picture.

[image: select workflow config based on branch]

Comment: Is there anyways to run workflow from github rest api? , Note: this is not a re run job, I need for run workflow.

Comment: I got solution for this questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151645/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-dispatch-from-github-api

Comment: I tried microset's solution but `gh workflow list` only showed the workflows I can already run via GH, not the new workflow_dispatch that isn't on the main branch.

Answer (score 10):

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch: {}
  push:
    branches:
      - 'feature/name-of-feature-branch'
```

Trigger workflow on **push** and define your branch under **branches:**. When your development is done and ready to merge main remove unnecessary code.

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch: {}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO