# How to trigger a `workflow_dispatch` from Github API?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

From the [GH Rest API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event), seems we're able to create a `repository_dispatch` event, but no `workflow_dispatch` event. In the [GH GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations), I couldn't find how to dispatch events.

Is it even possible to trigger a `workflow_dispatch` event using the API?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, **manually**, **through the Github API** or using the **GH CLI**.

### Manually (through the `Actions` tab on your repository.)

[Here is an official documentation about it](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/)

Basically, once you select the workflow on the tab, if the workflow implementation has the *workflow_dispatch* trigger, the option `Run workflow` will appear on the right part of the window, like this:

[image]

### With the Github API

On the official Github Documentation, there is a service to [create a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)

Here is a curl example:

```bash
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/actions/workflows/42/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"main"}'
```

Note that you can also send workflow `inputs` through this API as well.

You can also find more references about this [in this article](https://www.enekoalonso.com/articles/issue-7).

*There is also **another** Github API service to trigger [repository_dispatch events](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event).*

### GH CLI

You can also trigger a `workflow_dispatch` event using the [GH CLI tool](https://cli.github.com/) through the command:

`gh workflow run [<workflow-id> | <workflow-name>] [flags]`

> Create a workflow_dispatch event for a given workflow.

> This command will trigger GitHub Actions to run a given workflow file. The given workflow file must support a workflow_dispatch 'on' trigger in order to be run in this way.

[Reference](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run).

#### Bonus

*If you're looking for triggering those `workflow_dispatch` events (and `repository_dispatch` events) through a terminal command line, you can use [this automation in Python](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-github/tree/master/github/trigger/workflow). The implementation can be found [in this class](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-github/blob/master/github/trigger/workflow/src/formula/formula.py).*

Comment: calling `https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/actions/workflows/42/dispatches` with workflow_id is not possible to get from a feature branch if the workflow didn't run. If there is anyway to find the workflow_id from a fraure branch let me know.

Comment: _If there is anyway to find the workflow_id from a feature branch let me know_. The workflow id is generated automatically by Github, it's not related to the repository or its branches :/

Comment: The github API POST shown above does not work on feature branches.

Comment: @DeanSchulze yes it will not work on feature branch with workflow id but there is a workaround https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event replace workflow_id with the workflow file name. How ever on feature branch make sure your workflow_dispatch and push are same indenatation.

Answer (score 8):

You can also trigger `workflow_dispatch` via the [GH CLI tool](https://cli.github.com/): [`gh workflow run` docs](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run).

E.g.: `gh workflow run <WORKFLOW_ID> -f param_1=foo`

- You can get workflow IDs via `gh workflow list`.

Or you can also use the workflow file name instead of the workflow ID.

E.g.: `gh workflow run staging.yml -f param_1=foo`

Answer (score 4):

Workflow ID can also by the *workflow file name*

```
  curl \
    -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/<USER>/<REPO>/actions/workflows/build.yaml/dispatches \
    -d '{"ref":"main"}'
```

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of python code to trigger GitHub workflow.

You can get the workflow ID via `gh workflow list`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71972073/1661491

`github_token` is the classic personal token, see: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

`workflow_ref` is the branch or tag.

```py
import requests
import json

parameter_dict = ...
github_token = ...
workflow_ref = ...
workflow_id = ...
org = ...
repo_name = ..

inputs_str = json.dumps(parameter_dict)

response = requests.post( 
 f"https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo_name}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/dispatches",
  headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {github_token}"},
  data=f'{{"ref": "{workflow_ref}", "inputs": {inputs_str}}}'
)

if response.status_code >= 400:
  raise ValueError(f"Failed to trigger workflow: {response.status_code} {response.text}")
```

Comment: This is great! Github featured ghapi (https://github.blog/2020-12-18-learn-about-ghapi-a-new-third-party-python-client-for-the-github-api/), a Python library which allows you to also do this. If you're just wanting to create workflows it's probably not worth pulling in `ghiapi`, but if you need other parts it could be handy.


The call is `actions.create_workflow_dispatch(owner, repo, workflow_id, ref, inputs)`, which does what the above answer does.