# Trigger GitHub Action by a commit in different git repository without Personal Access Token

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'd like on commit in https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp to trigger GitHub Action in https://github.com/linux-test-project/linux-test-project.github.com. Is that possible?

I believe it would work via gitlab pipelines. If possible, it would help me to avoid Personal Access Token (avoid security problems).

But maybe I'm wrong, latest note in [example](https://gist.github.com/Daniel-ltw/552b90800b07c22e4a83dfa68ada6318?permalink_comment_id=4153968#gistcomment-4153968) mentions https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-from-a-workflow, which states that I need to use personal access token :(.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to trigger a pipeline based on an event from another repository. An option is to use a [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) trigger on the second repository, and send a [dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) from the first repository. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151645/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-dispatch-from-github-api) might give you some insights about how to do it.

Comment: It looks like this way also requires personal access token. It'd be great if the secret could stay within the organization (i.e. here within https://github.com/linux-test-project/).

Comment: According to what you shared, both repositories are from the same `linux-test-project` organization. If that's the case, the PAT secret could be used at the ORG level and would stay within the ORG.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token "Personal access tokens are intended to access GitHub resources on behalf of yourself. To access resources on behalf of an organization, or for long-lived integrations, you should use a GitHub App." I was not able to find a way to set PAT for organisation.

Comment: As a workaround, you could create an "organization user" that would be used only for sharing secrets or perform automated operations inside the organization. That way, everybody in the ORG could use secrets from this user account in the ORG workflows.

Comment: This is not optimal - completely unrelated new GitHub account would have to be managed by somebody => my solution to use custom GitHub Actions workflow in https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp (and not use https://github.com/linux-test-project/linux-test-project.github.com) will be better in long term.

Answer (score 0):

> Personal access tokens are intended to access GitHub resources on
> behalf of yourself. To access resources on behalf of an organization,
> or for long-lived integrations, you should use a GitHub App.
> ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token))

=> It looks like it's not possible in GitHub Actions to create workflows across repositories without Personal Access Token.

I needed this for updating repository which publish github pages. In the end instead having the content of the web page in custom repository https://github.com/linux-test-project/linux-test-project.github.com I'll add into sources repository https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp script which generates the sources on the fly and create (in https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp) [custom GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow) which will publish the sources. https://github.com/linux-test-project/linux-test-project.github.com will not be needed any more and will be deleted.