# How to trigger a Github action workflow on Jenkins job status check?

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I have a situation where i have to trigger a GitHub action workflow for every Pull Request, based on following conditions:

- Only when "Jenkins" build is success (Check status for Jenkins is green)
- Jenkins job is getting triggered only based on webhooks for each PR

[image: Requirement]

I was exploring GitHub events for trigger, but couldn't find any. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: I’m not familiar at all with the issue, but would [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow#defining-prerequisite-jobs) help?

Comment: @bfontaine Thanks for you suggestion. That would be helpful, if we are handling all jobs using a GitHub action workflow file. Here i am only having github action job in workflow, which i want to run. Jenkins is getting triggered from Pull request directly.

Comment: You could trigger the github workflow using a [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event, and send a [dispatch event request through the Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) at the end of the Jenkins workflow when performed successfully (using github cli on jenkins is also an option). The [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151645/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-dispatch-from-github-api) might be useful.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks for sharing the thread. I got some good insights out of it.