# Triggering github actions workflow from JIRA Board

Tags: github-actions, jira, github-api

I have GitHub actions pipeline i want to execute that pipeline from JIRA board whenever status change or when we comment on it. I found that GitHub providing repository dispatch event with that we can trigger pipeline from outside of GitHub action but I don't know exactly how?

I am new to the GitHub actions

Comment: You can directly call the github API to send a [dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event). This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151645/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-dispatch-from-github-api) might also give you some insights.